# How to pass a Comma seperated String to select options in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this Json:

```
        {
                "field_id": "4otBG",
                "label": "Fullness",
                "type": "dropdown",
                "props": {
                    "req": "true",
                    "options": "Empty-ish, Plenty of Seats, Few Seats, Standing, Packed Like Sardines"
                }
            }
```

How to pass the Options to an selection option , because it is a comma separated string  Please help me..

Comment: Repeated stackoverflow.com/questions/19718609/split-for-ng-repeat-item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have got you data in $scope.data

```
$scope.optionsplit =  $scope.data.props.options.split(',');
```

In view

```
<select name="yourinput">
   <option ng-repeat="o in optionsplit" value="{{o}}">{{o}}</option>
<select>
```

Or with ng-options

```
<select ng-options="o for o in optionsplit">

</select>
```

or you can make a filter for it

```
filter('commaspliter', function() {
    return function(input) {
    return input.split(',');
    } 
  });
```

In view

```
<select name="yourinput">
<option ng-repeat="o in data.props.options | commaspliter"></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I upvote this but I would create a custom filter instead and use ng-repeat="props.options | splitFilter"

Comment: thanks A.B.  you are great... :-) u saved my day.. your last option is correct worked for me...

Comment: @ParvindraSingh my pleasure you can accept it as answer so the question can be closed and helps other as well :)

Answer (score 2):

The angular way would be to use a filter. Note you're not supposed to use `$` prefix, but since this is such a general purpose filter I thought it was appropriate. Feel free to rename.

```
.filter('$split', function() {
  return function(val, splitter) {
    if (!splitter) { splitter = ','; }
    return (val && val.length) ? val.split(splitter) : [];
  }
});
```

Use it like so.

```
<select ng-options="val for val in props.options | $split" />
```

You can even pass an additional param if you have data that is delimited by a different character.

```
<select ng-options="val for val in props.options | $split:'|'" />
```

Comment: added this 31 second before ;)

Comment: Mine has more functionality :P